# ul > li replace color with image (depends on #color condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify

I am trying to replace ul > li background color with image it is condition-based depending on #color. I have tried with css but no luck.

Help is appreciated

```
<ul class="tt-options-swatch options-middle filtres-js">
  <li>
    <a class="options-color" style="background:#000000" href="/collections/black">Black</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="options-color" style="background:#FFFFFF" href="/collections/white">White</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="options-color" style="background:#ccccff" href="/collections/violet">Violet </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So what I am trying to do is IF style="background:#ccccff" then replace with image.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Main problem is that you want to change the `ul>li` depending on color but you are applying the color to the `a`. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried in css element.style {
1.     background: #ccccff;
2.     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0105/7708/4363/files/color-multi_small.png?v=1593179030) no-repeat center center;
}

Comment: Can you change the source/html at all?  Specifically, remove the `style=` and give each row a different class?

Comment: You *could* reference the element with `$("[style='background:#000000']")`, but it would be very brittle.

Comment: @nzone note that `background` CSS is a shorthand property, you need to check for the specific style (`background-color`), but again, if you are checking on the `li`, you won't find anything there, because you are applying the color to `a`, not to the `li`

Comment: that's not possible. as it's in a template.

Comment: please help how can I replace it for <a all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've made a clumsy example of how to do it here:

https://codepen.io/javiercampos/pen/abwwrWX

The code:

```js
  $('ul>li').each(function() {
    if($(this).children().css("background-color") == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(//media.istockphoto.com/vectors/abstract-blurred-colorful-background-vector-id1185382671?k=20&m=1185382671&s=612x612&w=0&h=QvHSiV0uDYhl69m1rpIt0aYbk4vmpl9kjVcfkMkgyfw=)'); 
      $(this).children().css('background-color', "");
    }
    if($(this).children().css("background-color") == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(//miuc.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/How-can-colours-help-you-in-your-everyday-life.jpg)'); 
      $(this).children().css('background-color', "");
    }
  });
```

Note that I'm checking for the background-color CSS property that returns a string in the form `rgb(x, y, z)`, not necessarily how it's applied in the HTML.

I'm also removing the background color in the `a` (in all direct descendants of the `li` basically) because that's probably what you want.

Note that this solution is pretty clumsy and will only work if the HTML is exactly how you paint it in the question, but it might be a start (also, the chosen images do not represent "white" or "black" at all, they are the first two results from google images searching for "color image")

See if it helps you

Comment: Hello, I tried this but it does not work with shopify.

Comment: var theme = {},
     money_format = '€{{amount_with_comma_separator}}',
        color_with_border = 'White' || 'empty',
        colors_value = ',multi: #ccccff,yellow: #ffff00,zwart: #000000,blue: #0000ff,green: #00ff00,purple: #800080,silver: #c0c0c0,white: #ffffff,brown: #7b3f00,light-brown: #feb035,dark-turquoise: #23cddc,orange: #fe9001,tan: #eacea7,violet: #ee82ee,pink: #ffc0cb,grey: #808080,rood: #ff0000,light blue: #add8e6,',
     texture_obj = function(){return JSON.parse('{}');
    }

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about shopify... more likely if that html snippet is written by javascript, you'll need to time your function to happen -after- it's rendered. What I put there is basic jquery + js and should work wherever you have those, taken the html is already rendered and in the DOM at the time you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

note: You set bgcolor on anchor tag. You can use window.getComputedStyle(list).backgroundColor for each element Like this

```js
// select all a tag
var lists = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li > a');

// looping foreach
lists.forEach(list => {
  const bgcol = window.getComputedStyle(list).backgroundColor;
  console.log(bgcol);
  bgcol == 'rgb(204, 204, 255)' ? console.log('Change to Img') : console.log('Skip');
})
```

```html
<ul class="tt-options-swatch options-middle filtres-js">
<li>
<a class="options-color" style="background:#000000"  href="/collections/black">Black</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="options-color" style="background:#FFFFFF"  href="/collections/white">White</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="options-color" style="background:#ccccff"  href="/collections/violet">Violet </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

but window.getComputedStyle(list).backgroundColor return rgb, note a hexa color like `#fff

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just put the style inside the data attribute?
`<a class="options-color" style="background:#FFFFFF" data-style="white"  href="#">White</a>`.

This way you could get the value of the data and use as `href`.

`const hrefColor = element.dataset.style`
then
`element.href = '/collections/'+hrefColor`